# How to compare two lists and get all indices of matches

Tags: python

This is probably a simple question that I am just missing but I have two lists containing strings and I want to "bounce" one, element by element, against the other returning the index of the matches. I expect there to be multiple matches and want all of the indices.  I know that list.index() gets the first and you can easily get the last. For example:

```
list1 = ['AS144','401M','31TP01']

list2 = ['HDE342','114','M9553','AS144','AS144','401M']
```

Then I would iterate through list1 comparing to list2 and output:
`[0,0,0,1,1,0] , [3,4]`  or etc for the first iteration
`[0,0,0,0,0,1] , [6]` for second
and `[0,0,0,0,0,0]` or `[]` for third

EDIT:
Sorry for any confusion. I would like to get the results in a way such that I can then use them like this- I have a third list lets call list3 and I would like to get the values from that list in the indices that are outputed. ie `list3[previousindexoutput]=list of cooresponding values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[([int(item1 == item2) for item2 in list2], [n for n, item2 in enumerate(list2) if item1 == item2]) for item1 in list1]
```

Answer (score 10):

Personally I'd start with:

`matches = [item for item in list1 if item in list2]`

Comment: This is very good and I feel like it could be easily modified to give index values instead of list of the values that match.

Comment: @Kosig: Well, of course, that was the point; if you want the indexes of matches, you do stuff like `indices = [list1.index(i) for i in list2]` or vice versa.

Comment: I'd cache list2 in a `set` first, because otherwise, you're getting O(n*n) performance.

Answer (score 3):

*This does not answer the question. See my comment below.*

As a start:

```
list(i[0] == i[1] for i in zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: This returns `[False, False, False]` for me.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood the question. My code returns a list with `True` or `False` if the items at the same index of the two lists are the same. E.g. for `list1 = [1, 2, 3]` and `list2 = [1, 2, 4]` it returns `[True, True, False]`. Vote my answer down if you like :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
def findInstances(list1, list2):
    """For each item in list1,
    return a list of offsets to its occurences in list2
    """

    for i in list1:
        yield [pos for pos,j in enumerate(list2) if i==j]

list1 = ['AS144','401M','31TP01']
list2 = ['HDE342','114','M9553','AS144','AS144','401M']

res = list(findInstances(list1, list2))
```

results in

```
[[3, 4], [5], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you want these packaged up, but this does the work:

```
def matches(lst, value):
    return [l == value for l in lst]

all_matches = [matches(list2, v) for l in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want and it can be easily turned into a generator:

```
>>> [[i for i in range(len(list2)) if item1 == list2[i]] for item1 in list1]
[[3, 4], [5], []]
```

Here is a version with a slightly different output format:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i in range(len(list1)) for j in range(len(list2)) if list1[i] == list2[j]]
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give a list of lists with True/False values instead of 1/0:

```
matches = [ [ list1[i] == list2[j] for j in range(0, len(list2)) ] for i in range(0, len(list1)) ]
```

Edit:  If you're using 2.5 or later, this should give 1's & 0's:

```
matches = [ [ 1 if list1[i] == list2[j] else 0 for j in range(0, len(list2)) ] for i in range(0, len(list1)) ]
```

Comment: Yes. The second is exactly what I was looking for. However now I have those indices, how do I get their cooresponding values from another list?

Comment: @Kosig:  I'm not clear on what else you want.  What do you mean by "how do I get their cooresponding (sic) values from another list?" Is there a different list that you've not mentioned in the question?  Or do you want to access the original values in list1/list2?  Are you trying to use the matches list for that?