# Python - Find the indices of elements of a list that match elements of another list

Tags: python

I have a longer list containing strings representing unique dates.

```
dates = ['20171021', '20171031', '20171102', '20171225', '20180101', '20180106',
 '20180126', '20180131', '20180312', '20180315', '20180330', '20180409',
 '20180414', '20180419', '20180421', '20180424', '20180426', '20180429',
 '20180501', '20180516', '20180524', '20180603', '20180605', '20180608', '20180613']
```

and a shorter list of strings with part of the dates (only those I am interested in)

```
selected_dates = ['20171021',  '20180106', '20180414', '20180426']
```

I want to use the second list to find the indices of the elements in the larger list that match the dates in this second list so the result would be

```
[0, 5, 12, 16]
```

Edit:

What I found by now is that I can use

```
dates.index('20171021')
```

to find a single index, but I cannot use

```
dates.index(selected_dates)
```

because this will search if list 2 is an element of list 1.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you post what you've tried? Have you looked at similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937634/in-python-how-to-compare-two-lists-and-get-all-indices-of-matches/4937777

Comment: You can use a nested for loop and simple comparison to solve this. Try and share what you did first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.index()` in a list comprehension:

```
dates = ['20171021', '20171031', '20171102', '20171225', '20180101', '20180106',
 '20180126', '20180131', '20180312', '20180315', '20180330', '20180409',
 '20180414', '20180419', '20180421', '20180424', '20180426', '20180429',
 '20180501', '20180516', '20180524', '20180603', '20180605', '20180608', '20180613']

selected_dates = ['20171021',  '20180106', '20180414', '20180426']

filtered_dates = [dates.index(i) for i in selected_dates] #Find the index value of i in dates for each value in selected_dates
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 12, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `index` method.

```
>>> for date in selected_dates:
    print(dates.index(date))
0
5
12
16
```